# Error while getting the result from the wcf service in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf, wcfserviceclient

Am using silverlight4.0 and using the WCF service and my functnalities are working fine and at some point of time am getting an exception as like "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." this was inner exception message and the response status code is"System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound".can anyone help for this ..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that silverlight always shows not found error in many cases, the first thing that can be is that service really not available, second try to make sure that you service function is not throwing exception
Try opening the wcf service in the browser,
also [this](http://blog.benday.com/archive/2010/08/16/23286.aspx) can help to investigate problem
And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470096%28VS.96%29.aspx) is how you can configure to send real exception to client